# How to use finder methods on join table values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join

In my Ruby on Rails app, i've created a join table in my database to link customers and businesses. Now i'm trying to find information on one of the models based on the information in the join table (called "conflicts"):

@customer = Customer.where(customer_id: 1).conflict(s) **Or**
@customer = Customer.find(1).conflict(s)

I want to find information about the customer (or business) directly tied to a given "conflict", and print that to the browser view.

Error i'm getting now:
**undefined method `conflicts' for #**

Comment: Can you show us how your associations are defined?

Answer (score 0):

To get conflict through customer you should have following association in Customer model(customer.rb),

has_one :conflict
OR
has_many :conflicts

Comment: Thank you for your response....I am trying to update the model but keep getting a NameError. Even after I dropped the database. I have recently installed Devise and OAuth in my project folder. Is there a workaround for updating the models and also storing data in my seeds to use to test the app?

Comment: Can you share your schema?

Answer (score 0):

As per the description provided you have created a join table having the reference of both customers and businesses.

And the error you have provided, it seems like you forgot to associate them in your models.

customer.rb

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :customer_conflicts
  has_many: conflicts, through: :customer_conflicts
end
```

conflict.rb

```
class Conflict < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :customer_conflicts
   has_many :customers, through: :customer_conflicts
end
```

customer_conflict.rb

```
class CustomerConflict < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :customer
 belongs_to :conflict
end
```

Now running the below mentioned queries will work:

```
@customer = Customer.where(customer_id: 1).conflicts
@customer = Customer.find(1).conflicts
```

Comment: Thank you for your response....I am trying to update the model but keep getting a NameError. Even after I dropped the database. I have recently installed Devise and OAuth in my project folder. Is there a workaround for updating the models and also storing data in my seeds to use to test the app?